# Windows Phone C# Remove Last Canvas Line

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, canvas

Hi I'm trying to remove the last line entered on a Canvas but I'm only able to delete certain oart of it this is my code...

```
if (this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Count > 0)
        { this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Count - 1) ;
```

or...

```
IEnumerable<Line> linesOne = ContentPanelCanvas.Children.OfType<Line>();
        if (linesOne.Count() >= 5) { 
        this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(linesOne.Count() - 5);
        }
```

Only delete part of it not the full last entered line
Code for draw line...

```
currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this.ContentPanelCanvas) ;
            Line line = new Line() { X1 = currentPoint.X, Y1 = 
            currentPoint.Y, X2 =        oldPoint.X,     Y2 = oldPoint.Y } ;

            line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black ) ;
            line.StrokeThickness = SliderOne.Value ;
            line.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round ;
            line.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round ;
            this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Add(line) ;
            oldPoint = currentPoint ;
```

Can someone please help me...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with this

`UIElement line=this.canvas.Children[this.canvas.Children.Count-1];
this.canvas.Children.Remove(line);`

you can remove the last element in Children collection.

Comment: I am using that for wp8.1 silverlight. Can I remove a point or portion from a line, not full line. Also I have a background image of canvas.

Comment: you can resize the line, or not?

Comment: No, I can't resize the line.